# Using azure.identity.UsernamePasswordCredential and error: AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID

Tags: java, azure

I am using the microsoft graph-sdk-java to read canlendar from outlook with a User scope by using UsernamePasswordCredential authorization. First, I try to get user's information.

```
        final UsernamePasswordCredential usernamePasswordCredential = new UsernamePasswordCredentialBuilder()
                .clientId(CLIENT_ID)
                .username(username)
                .password(password)
                .build();

        final TokenCredentialAuthProvider tokenCredentialAuthProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(getScopes(), usernamePasswordCredential);

        final GraphServiceClient<Request> graphClient = GraphServiceClient
                        .builder()
                        .authenticationProvider(tokenCredentialAuthProvider)
                        .buildClient();

        final User me = graphClient.me().buildRequest().get();
```

Then, I running the program and have a problem below.

```
com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalInteractionRequiredException: AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID <application_id>. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.
```

The application has been registered in the tenant's Azure AD. I think there's a problem with app's API permissions.

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMXYF.png)]

How do I handler this error and get calendar's event without interactive authorization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

> **Note** that: To get/read the calendar, the Azure AD Application must have **`Calendars.Read`** API permission.

I created an **Azure AD Application and granted API permissions** like below:

[image]

Now I generated **access token** via Postman using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
username:user1@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com
password:****
grant_type:password
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

[image]

Make sure the **`Calendars.Read`**  API permission is present when you decode the token like below:

[image]

**I am able to get the calendar details successfully like below:**

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar
```

[image]